# Nuxt/Vuex object with Firebase DocumentReference causes [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, nuxt.js

So I have this issue where creating a snapshot to the collection keeps getting me the error:

`[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers`

The code I have is as follows. I have an Action in the Vuex store to create a snapshot of the collection in firestore. Having the `doc.ref` is what is causing me the issue. If I remove this the mutation goes through without a problem. But if I leave the `doc.ref` I get the previously mentioned error.

```
 getAllProjects({commit, state}) {
    firebase.firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(state.loggedInUser.id)
        .collection("projects")
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            let projects = []
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                let pr = new Project(doc.ref, doc.id, doc.data().title, doc.data().languages, doc.data().baseLanguage);
                projects.push(pr);
            })
            commit('setProjects', [...projects]);
        });
}
```

Mutation:

```
setProjects(state, projects) {
    state.projects = projects
},
```

Comment: I am pretty sure your issue is somewhere else. What else does the debugger console print? I had similar problem and found the source of issue by looking at the printed stack trace in debug console.

Comment: Not sure if the issue is somewhere else beacuse as i mentioned removeing the doc.ref and DocumentReference property in the Project class fixes the issue. I will try and get the stack trace

Comment: @M.Hazara https://pastebin.com/vU1w4bWa link to the Error full stack trace. Also to note when the snapshot is loaded the first time it works, changing something in Firebase Dashboard to trigger the snapshot then it shows the error.